# Unable to launch new dask SLURM cluster from jupyter lab - "No module named 'dask_jobqueue"

Tags: dask, jupyter-lab

I am trying to launch a new SLURM cluster using the Dask extension in JupyterLab. I am encountering the following pop-up when I click on the '+New' button:

Cluster Start Error
No module named 'dask_jobqueue'

This is despite having a labextension.yaml file in ~/.config/dask with a module for 'dask_jobqueue' included. This screenshot shows the issue, as well as my config file in the background:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the module has to be installed with:

```sh
conda install -c conda-forge dask-jobqueue
```

The image you had was showing a reference to the module (but it was not installed).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This step wasn't included in the setup I was using and I didn't realize there was a package to grab from conda.